# Prove that any set X has exactly one power set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Intuitively this makes sense, as the power set is the set of all subsets of X. So far I have assumed P,Q are two distinct power sets, then for any $a \in P, a \subset X$ so $a \in Q$. Which gives $P \subset Q$, the other direction gives $Q \subset P$. But I am not sure it is complete?

Answer (score 3):

The axiom of extensionality states sets are equal iff they have the same elements, which completes a proof there is *at most one* power set. That there is one is guaranteed by another axiom of most set theories, the power set axiom.